# How can I define a different padding value for IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I need to assign a different padding value in Internet Explorer, because when I declare the height for a `<div>` it calculates it as height + padding (it's working fine in both Firefox and Chrome).

Here is my CSS:

```
#payment{
    width: 265px;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(50,50,50,0.46);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(50,50,50,0.46);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(50,50,50,0.46);
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    /*display: block;*/
    position: absolute;
    /*float: right;*/
    height: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 549px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at using [Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) or [IE Specific Stylesheets](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: in your case use `width:245px;` and `height:210px;` and it will work without any issues !

Comment: If you found IE includes padding into sizing, specify `(moz-)box-sizing:border-box` to use the same model across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this :

```
#payment{
    padding: 10px; /* standard */
    padding: 17px\9; /* IE 8 and below */
    *padding: 15px\9; /* IE 7 and below */
    _padding: 16px\9; /* IE 6 */
}
```

[reference link 1](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer)

[reference link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890740/are-there-any-ie9-css-hacks)

Answer (score 3):

You can add IE conditionals to the html element and assign classes to specific IE versions.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en-us" class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en-us" class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en-us" class="lt-ie9 ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can target your selector with the IE class prepended.

```
.lt-ie8 #payment { /* IE7 & below */
    padding: 5px;
}
```

or

```
.ie7 #payment { /* IE7 only */
    padding: 5px;
}
```